# How to access <div> elements outside the <body> tag?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I made a script that connects to a WP video plugin and generates a floating menu over it. The script works fine inside the WP page but it does not work when I use the plugins SHARE&EMBED function when it generates a link to my video that is used to incorporate it into another page structure. When embedding the into the outside webpage my custom Js script does not work. Better to say it works because my js and css files get connected to the head of the new page and the menu is present inside the structure of the page but it is covered by the new div elements generated by the plugin.

WordPress video plugin that I use generates an iframe tag. When I examine the page in which I embed the link to the video, in developer mode, I see that the  is placed inside a  tag that is outside the page's  tag. When I try to access the Iframe tag with document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") or by its' id I get an error message that the element does not exist. I tried to use "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',..." and "if(window.fwduvpPlayer0)..." but it still i can not access the the  tag with my video.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function displayMenuBtnOverVideo() {
    generateMainMenuButton1();``
    if (window.fwduvpPlayer0 && document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") != null) {
        shareAndEmbed();
    }
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function displayMenuBtnOverVideo() {
    generateMainMenuButton1();``
    if (window.fwduvpPlayer0 && document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") != null) {
        shareAndEmbed();
    }
});

function shareAndEmbed() {
    let getIFrameDiv = document.document.getElementById("fwduvpPlayer0youtube");

   getIFrameDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",
        `<div class="show-menu top-left" id="menuBtnDiv1">
             <button class="btn btn-sm" id="menuBtn" onclick="videoOverlayMenuGenerator1()">
             <span class="iconify" data-icon="whh:menu" data-inline="false"></span><span class="menu-button-title"> MENU emb</span>
             </button>
             </div>`
    );
```

The idea is that I want my script to access he iFrame tag by its' id and include before it the div tag with the code for my custom menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the `document` property within `document`. That property does not exist.

```
let getIFrameDiv = document.document.getElementById("fwduvpPlayer0youtube");
```

Maybe you tried to get the `<html>` tag which is the `documentElement` property in `document`.
`documentElement` only has three methods to select elements.

- `getElementsByClassName`
- `getElementsByTagName`
- `getElementsByTagNameNS`

Answer (score 0):

In order to access to a element that is not into the  tag, you can try to use this options:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById()
```

OR

```
window.top.document.getElementById()
```

Maybe, with this you would can to access to this elements.

I hope that this, help you.

Regards

Comment: `window.parent` and `window.top` both return `window`.